# Spanning set and its complements..

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S=\mathrm{span}\,\{\langle 1,2,1 \rangle, \langle 2,1,3 \rangle\}$. Find two complements of S in $\mathbb E^3$

What I am trying to show is that any two of the unit vectors of $\mathbb E^3$ cannot be written as a linear combination of $\langle 1,2,1 \rangle$ and $\langle 2,1,3 \rangle$. But not able to do so at last as they can be written as the linear combination.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "complements"?

Comment: Do you try to say orthogonal complement?

Comment: Not orthogonal complement it's general complement say a is complement of b if a+b=V(vector space)